# Trying to Read Value from Excel Through Loop and Storing to Environment Variable

Tags: vbscript, automation, automated-tests, environment-variables, hp-uft

I am trying to read values from Excel Data File and trying to store the values to environment variables. Then I want to reuse these environment variables in my tests.
However following code giving me unexpected run time error. With no error code no . When I fix the code with static excel (Row,Col) then I get the result but I need to control it through a loop. Need help.

```
For x = 2 to Row_TD         
    TDID = TestData_Sheet.Cells (x , "A")       
    IF TestData_Sheet.Cells (x,"B") = "Y" Then      
        fnReadData


Function fnReadData 
    Environment.Value("URL") = TestData_Sheet.Cells(x,"C") 
    msgbox environment.Value("URL") 
    Environment.Value("Browser") = TestData_Sheet.Cells(x,"D")  
    msgbox environment.Value("Browser") 
    Environment.Value("City") = TestData_Sheet.Cells(x,"E")  
    Environment.Value("Zip") = TestData_Sheet.Cells(x,"F")   
    Environment.Value("LoanAmount") = TestData_Sheet.Cells(x,"G")  
    Environment.Value("DownPayment") = TestData_Sheet.Cells(x,"H")  
    Environment.Value("Points") = TestData_Sheet.Cells(x,"I")  
    msgbox Environment.Value("Points") 
    Environment.Value("FICO") = TestData_Sheet.Cells(x,"J")
```

Comment: Please format your code as `code`........ Use it like ` + YOUR TEXT + ` or 4 spaces + YOUR TEXT

Comment: Hello, I am new here really no idea about formatting code.

Comment: Can you please be more specific on what error you are getting, which line number etc.

Comment: You're missing the `End If` and `Next` from the initial loop and the `End Function` from `fnReadData` so this wouldn't even execute as it is.  I've tidied it up but please provide the necessary details for a [mcve] to be worked with.

Comment: Also, x has no value inside `fnReadData` unless you pass it into the function...

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
TestData_Sheet.Cells(x,"E").Value 'Invalid
And
TestData_Sheet.Range("E"&x).value 'valid
TestData_Sheet.Cells(x,5).value   'valid
```

Comment: Hello,Thanks for reply. But issue is till the same.

Comment: This line TestData_Sheet.Range("E"&x).value  gives invalid arguments needed. Ladt line I dont want to hard code the row and col. Rather I want UFT to use iteration through for loop and get data through function .

Comment: Are you passing the value of x to fnReadData function. Can you tell me what is the value of x when you get the error. X is a local variable and has to be passed to the function, otherwise you may be getting variable undefined error.